# VBA IE engaging 'list' and selecting 'onchange' 'option values'

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer

I'm currently working on automation process which involves VBA and IE. Everything goes well up to date with multiple actions that my code is undertaking. The issue is when I approach a part where I have 2 dropdown lists, with second one appearing after certain selection is made in the first one.

The part of the code I have developed [which is rather crude] for this section is as follows:

```
Dim dropY As Object
Set dropY = IE.Document.getelementbyid("selectedListType")
dropY.Focus
Application.SendKeys "{DOWN 4}"

Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
Loop
Do Until .ReadyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
'second list
Dim dropZ As Object
Set dropZ = IE.Document.getelementbyid("dataSet")
dropZ.Focus 'I can see that the window is being selected
Application.SendKeys ("{DOWN 1}") 'at this point the code fails
Application.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
```

The Question is, how to approach the selection in both dropdown lists in order to avoid future errors? Below is the website source.

```
'first list
Select List Type
<select name="selectedListType" id="selectedListType" class="regular" onchange="onSubmitOrgConfig(2)">
<option value="Choice1"
>
Country Lists
</option>
<option value="Choice2"
>
Region Lists
</option>
<option value="Choice3"
>
Area Lists
</option>
<option value="Choice4"
>
Aggregated Lists
</option>
<option value="OTHER"
selected>
Other Lists
</option>
<option value="Other1"
>
Secure List
</option>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Select List
<select name="dataSet" id="dataSet" class="regular" onchange="onSubmitDataSet(6, this.value);">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="LIST_1"
>
BLACKLIST_LIST
</option>
<option value="LIST_2"
>
BLUE_LIST
</option>
<option value="LIST_3"
selected>
RED_LIST
</option>
<option value="LIST_4"
>
YELL_LIST
</option>
<option value="LIST_5"
>
PURP_LIST
</option>
<option value="LIST_6"
>
BL_LIST
</option>
<option value="LIST_7"
>
ORA_LIST
</option>
<option value="LIST_8"
>
NOCOL_LIST
</option>
<option value="LIST_999"
>
LIST_999
</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is SendKyes a typo? And is there an URL to share?

Comment: Yes it is a typo. Apologies. There is no publicly available URL am afraid.

Comment: I feel like the selection with sending keys to the lists is a bit primitive. Is there any other way which allows to select options in dropdowns by "name" instead of "my way"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr;**

Without a webpage to play with it is a little hard to advise on ordering of events and if everything below will work but hopefully it will help.

For example, I don't know if you have to do the Click on first list, select an item, then the javascript attached is automatically fired, or if you need to actually fire the event. Then if you have to repeat this for the second. So below, I have shown you how I would go about trying to achieve each of these actions individually so you can play with them to see what works. We can refine with feedback.

---

**selectedListType dropdown:**

You can try to click the first list with

```
.document.querySelector("#selectedListType").Click
```

You can select items from the first list with

```
.document.querySelector("#selectedListType [value='Choice1']")
```

Change `Choice1` as appropriate

So marked as `selected` could be

```
.document.querySelector("#selectedListType [value='Choice1']").Selected = True
```

---

**dataSet dropdown:**

You can try to click the second list with

```
.document.querySelector("#dataSet").Click
```

You can select items from the second list with

```
.document.querySelector("#dataSet option[value='LIST_1']")
```

Change `LIST_1` as appropriate

So marked as `selected` could be

```
.document.querySelector("#dataSet option[value='LIST_1']").Selected = True
```

---

**`onchange` event:**

Both lists have an `onchange` event:

You can trigger these with

```
 .document.querySelector("#selectedListType").FireEvent "onchange"
 .document.querySelector("#dataSet").FireEvent "onchange"
```